# HttpListener setting a total connection timeout

Tags: c#, httplistener

I am trying to control the maximum total duration of a single connection in `HttpListener`. I am aware of the `TimeoutManager` property and the 5 or so different timeout values that it contains but it is unclear whether or not setting each of those values will add up to the total places where delay may occur in a connection.

I am looking for something more along the lines of: "If we have a connection that lasts more than x s from the moment of opening the connection until now, abort it without sending anything else or waiting for anything else."

**EDIT**

To clarify, the scenario that I was experimenting with involves the server trying to send the response and the client not receiving. This causes `HttpListenerResponse.OutputStream.Write()` to hang indefinitely. I was trying to find a method that I can call from another thread to hard-abort the connection. I tried using `OutputStream.Close()` and got `Cannot Close Stream until all bytes are written`. I also tried `HttpListenerResponse.Abort()` which produced no visible effect.

Answer (score 4):

None of those properties will do what you want. HttpListener is intended to control the request flow, incomming and outgoing data, so it doesn't handle the time between when the response has been fully received and when you send a response, it's your responsability to take care of it.

You should create your own mechanism to abort the request if the total time is higer than the desired one, just a timer can be enough, when a new connection is created enqueue a timer with the total timeout as expiring time, if the request ends before the timer expires cancel the timer, else the timer aborts the request.